# PyQT Dialog Window with Toolbar

Tags: dialog, pyqt, toolbar

What is the standard approach of adding a toolbar to a dialog window in PyQT? I seem to be able to add toolbars only to a main window class.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature doesn't seem to be supported. See
[Can you add a toolbar to QDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435801/can-you-add-a-toolbar-to-qdialog) for answers to the same situation but in C++ and Qt.

However maybe you can just use a QMainWindow as a dialog window with a toolbar?